# Does the 2015 Retina MacBook have firmware target disk mode?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, target-disk-mode

I've read the [user manual](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP712) and [FAQ on ports](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204303) for the new 2015 Retina MacBook and can't tell if it supports target disk mode.

Apple's article on target disk explicitly says [Firewire and Thunderbolt are required for target disk mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201462) but the excellent [iMore review article](http://www.imore.com/macbook-2015-review) says:

> You can transfer data at up to 5 Gpbs over USB 3.1, USB 3, or USB 2, or over ethernet with a USB adapter. (Including target disk mode.)

For the purposes of this question - target disk mode is exposing the internal MacBook storage using firmware and not the OS X installed on the computer itself.

What is needed to place this Mac in target disk mode and connect it to another computer that would presumably see it as a USB 3.1 Gen 1 hard drive?

Answer (score 5):

Yes - you need an USB C data cable to use this and the power cable Apple ships isn't a data cable for these needs, but the firmware and hardware support target move over USB.

[Apple's MacBook ports article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204360) now has a section titled "USB Target Disk Mode":

> USB Target Disk Mode
>   Your MacBook with USB-C port supports USB Target Disk Mode. Enable Target Disk Mode for use with the following USB-C cables:
>   1) USB 3.0 or USB 3.1 USB-A to USB-C Cable 
>   Target Disk Mode can be used with this cable to manually transfer data from any Mac notebook with USB-A port(s) to your MacBook with USB-C port. This cable cannot be used to migrate data using the Setup Assistant or Migration Assistant application.
>   2) USB 3.0 or USB 3.1 USB-C Cable (USB-C to USB-C)
>   Target Disk Mode can be used to migrate data from any MacBook with a USB-C port to another MacBook with USB-C port using the Setup Assistant or Migration Assistant application. 
>   Note: These cables are not currently available from Apple.
>   To enable Target Disk Mode, hold down the T button on your keyboard while starting your MacBook. Then connect either USB-C cable described above. Note that the USB-C Charge Cable (2m) that comes with MacBook does not support Target Disk Mode.Your MacBook supports USB Target Disk Mode when you use it with a compatible, full-featured (“super speed”) USB-C cable. Note that the USB-C Charge Cable (included with MacBook) does not support USB Target Disk Mode.
>
> To enable Target Disk Mode, hold down the T button on your keyboard while starting your MacBook. Then connect the USB-C cable. Use a full-featured USB-C to USB-C cable to connect to another MacBook, or a full-featured USB-A to USB-C cable to connect to a Mac with standard USB-A ports.

Since this section was still available two days ago, and the MacBook launched on April 10, 2015 — I would say the answer is almost certainly yes, but not with the cable it comes with.

Comment: I know I saw Apple publishing those words, but didn't save a link / have the right archive/cache mojo. Thanks for digging that up! I was confused as well with that "USB-C Charge Cable" doesn't support TDM - so we'll probably have to dig up the super speed specifications.

Comment: This answer is now out of date in that the MacBook ports page doesn't mention Target Disk Mode, but the [Target Disk Mode page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201462) does explain the requirements for the MacBook. It remains correct that the Apple USB-C charge cable doesn't support USB 3.1 Target Disk Mode, but Apple now offer the Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) Cable which does.